# How to convert a String number into a int array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to take a String that is a number and convert it into an int array. The value for the string is created in the `generateNewSecret()` method and I'm trying to get this value converted into an int array and then store it in the instance `secretNumber`. The instance numDigits value is taken from another class and is used in here. The method `convertNumToDigitArray` is what I'm using to do this but I can't get this to work. I keep getting this error message:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Engine
{
private int numDigits;
private int[] secretNumber = new int[numDigits];
private Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();


public int[] convertNumToDigitArray(String number)
{
    int numDigits = number.length();
    int[] convertNumToDigitArray = new int[numDigits];
    for(int i = 0; i <= numDigits; i++)
    {
        convertNumToDigitArray[i] =  number.charAt(i);
    }
    return convertNumToDigitArray;
}

public int getNumDigits()
{
    return numDigits;
}

public int[] getSecretNumber()
{
    return this.secretNumber;
}

//creates a random number with a certain length that matches numDigits, 
 // stores in a string value
//Ex. numDigits = 3; secret = 647;
public void generateNewSecret()
{
    int secret = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i <= numDigits; i++)
    {

    secret = secret * 10 + randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(9);

    }
    secret = secret/10;
    String secretNum = Integer.toString(secret);

    setSecretNumber(convertNumToDigitArray(secretNum));


}


public void setNumDigits(int numDigits)
{
    this.numDigits = numDigits;
    secretNumber = new int[numDigits];
}

public void setSecretNumber(int[] secretNumber)
{

    this.secretNumber = secretNumber;
}
}
```

Comment: `i <= numDigits` should be `i < numDigits`.

Comment: Voting to close: off topic, typo

Comment: @Tibrogargan: Frankly, it looks more like a fundamental lack of understanding than a typo to me.

Comment: @KenY-N sure, but the question doesn't add any value to SO and that's probably the most applicable reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
int[] numArray = new int[numDigits];
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)
{
  numArray[i] = number.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```